# How to know if an object includes another one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a library able to say if an object B includes all property and values of an object A (and not the opposite !).

It means 2 things that the librairies i found do not handle:

1. The object B could have more keys than object A, and it could be
   true.
2. The object B could have more items in its arrays than object
   A, and it could be true.

This is basically what the method `_.difference()` of lodash does, but only for items in arrays.

i found interesting libraries like [deep-diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff), but anything for my need.

I could code something doing the job, but i am convinced other peoples met this need before.

Here is an example with 2 objects:

```
var A = {
  name: 'toto',
  pets: [ { name: 'woof', kind: 'dog' } ]
};

var B = {
  name: 'toto',
  pets: [ { name: 'gulp', kind: 'fish' }, { name: 'woof', kind: 'dog' } ],
  favoriteColor: 'blue'
};
```

Here, A includes B since we can find in B every properties and values of A.
But librairies like diff would say no, since this is not the first but the second item of "pets" which is equal to A, and B has an additionnal property "favoriteColor".

Do you know a librairy able to do this kind of comparison?

Comment: Questions looking for external libraries etc are off topic for Stack Overflow, so starting and finishing your question with such a request is likely to get it closed fairly quickly.  What would be more on topic is if you attempt such a thing yourself, and when you get stuck, post what you've done.  At that point someone will help, or you may get a few comments saying "have you tried just using x"

Comment: This is not a duplicate, we can easily see it by this line :
if (Object.keys(obj1).length !== Object.keys(obj2).length) {
        return false;
    };

I have enumerated 2 points in my post, thanks to ready the first one.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM.: Whoa, you've got me. I read that question, read the first answer, saw that it was good and tried to upvote it. Then got a "*You can't vote for your own post*" error :-) But no, it's not a duplicate, as those functions check for deep equality not for inclosure.

Comment: @Bergi ok, i remove the duplicate flag, then .... funny "You can't vote for your own post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a modified version of the deepCompare that was linked in the comments. Really you just need to get past the keys length comparison, it seems.

```js
// where b has all of a
function deepHas(a, b) {
  if (typeof a !== typeof b) {
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof a !== 'object') {
    return a === b;
  }

  // you may need to polyfill array higher-order functions here
  if(Array.isArray(a) && Array.isArray(b)) {
    return a.every(function(av) {
      return b.indexOf(av) !== -1;
    });
  }
  
  if (Object.keys(a).length > Object.keys(b).length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var k in a) {
    if (!(k in b)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!deepHas(a[k], b[k])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


var a1 = {
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: {
    baz: {
      baz: 'wee'
    }
  }
};

var b1 = {
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: {
    baz: {
      baz: 'wee',
      whatever: 'wat'
    }
  },
  ok: 'test'
};

console.log('b1 has all of a1', deepHas(a1, b1));

var a2 = {
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  bar: 'bar',
  baz: {
    baz: {
      baz: 'wee'
    }
  }
};

var b2 = {
  foo: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  baz: {
    baz: {
      baz: 'wee'
    }
  }
};

console.log('b2 does not have all of a2', !deepHas(a2, b2));

console.log('["a","b"] has ["b"]', deepHas(["b"], ["a","b"]));

console.log('{foo: ["a","b"]} has {foo: ["b"]}', deepHas({ foo: ["b"] }, { foo:["a","b"] }));
```

Comment: @Bergi - that's easily fixed.

Comment: Yes of course :-) It should be `b.some(deephas.bind(null, av))` though instead of `indexOf`